# Function Returning NaN

Tags: java, algorithm, nan, factorial, exponent

I created a program that calculates this algorithm starting at k=1 and ending it k=100:

[image: formula]

Here's the code that I've created:

```
public static void calculatePi() {
    BigInteger firstFactorial;
    BigInteger secondFactorial;
    BigInteger firstMultiplication;
    BigInteger firstExponent;
    BigInteger secondExponent;
    int firstNumber = 1103;
    BigInteger firstAddition;
    double summationPi = 3.0;
    double currentPi = 3.0;
    double pi = 3.0;
    int secondNumber = 2;
    double thirdNumber = Math.sqrt(2.0);
    int fourthNumber = 9801;
    double prefix = 1;

    for(int i=1;i<101;i++){
        firstFactorial = factorial(4*i);
        secondFactorial = factorial(i);
        firstMultiplication = BigInteger.valueOf(26390*i);
        firstExponent = exponent(secondFactorial, 4);
        secondExponent = exponent(BigInteger.valueOf(396),4*i);
        firstAddition = BigInteger.valueOf(firstNumber).add(firstMultiplication);
        summationPi = firstFactorial.intValue()*firstAddition.intValue();
        summationPi /= firstExponent.intValue()*secondExponent.intValue();
        currentPi += summationPi;
    }

    prefix = secondNumber*thirdNumber;
    prefix = prefix/fourthNumber;

    summationPi = summationPi*prefix;

    pi = 1/summationPi;

    System.out.println("Pi is: " + pi);

    return;
}
```

The function exponent(a,b); returns the result of a^b. The function factorial(a) returns the factorial of a. I have proven that both of these functions work perfectly. However, the code seems to mysteriously be returning "NaN." I understand that this happens when something is divided by zero, however I have not been able to find any point at which something is divided by zero. Is there anything else that would cause this/I'm doing wrong?

Note: In the for statement, I'm using i as k in the algorithm.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: NaN is typically caused by dividing 0 by 0 (see other possible causes here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Creation).  You should step through your code in a debugger, or add lots of print statements, in order to isolate the first calculation that results in NaN.

Comment: @DanW: I suspect that's what the OP is setting out to demonstrate (see the function name)...

Comment: @DanW I know that, that's just a place holder :).

Comment: @Toby It was intended more to be a joke comment.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much more efficient to just do `return 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841;`? Or perhaps define a constant?

Answer (score 2):

### Problem:

These lines are likely where the error is happening:

```
summationPi = firstFactorial.intValue()*firstAddition.intValue();
summationPi /= firstExponent.intValue()*secondExponent.intValue();
```

The reason being that you are calling `intValue()` on a `BigInteger`, which is not guaranteed to return the full value (since an `int` can only hold 32 bits of data. This could also come in to play with storing the result as a `double` instead of a `BigDecimal`).

You then take that possible `NaN` value and use it as the divisor in your division.

### Solution:

```
BigDecimal currentPi = BigDecimal.ONE;

currentPi = currentPi.add(
  new BigDecimal(firstFactorial.multiply(firstAddition))
    .divide(new BigDecimal(firstExponent.multiply(secondExponent)), new MathContext(10000)));
```

Notice that I am able to eliminate `summationPi` by combining multiple lines into one. Also, the `MathContext` that comes up in the `divide()` method is set to `10000`, this can be changed to any accuracy you want.

For more information on `BigDecimal`, [check the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: Doing that is giving me a lot of errors because firAddition, firstExponent and secondExponent aren't BigDecimals but rather BigIntegers.

Comment: I get this whenever I run the code (line 53 is your code)  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.
 at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:1603)
 at picalculator.PiCalculator.calculatePi(PiCalculator.java:53)
 at picalculator.PiCalculator.main(PiCalculator.java:24)
Java Result: 1

Comment: @Toby that's a function of `MathContext`. I'll update it again. Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.
 at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:1603)
 at picalculator.PiCalculator.calculatePi(PiCalculator.java:60)
 at picalculator.PiCalculator.main(PiCalculator.java:25)
Java Result: 1

Comment: I think that line is: `prefix = prefix/fourthNumber`. You need to apply the same concept of `BigDecimal` and `MathContext` to `prefix` as well.

Comment: I'm doing this:

prefix = secondNumber*thirdNumber;
prefix = prefix/fourthNumber;
currentPi = currentPi.multiply(new BigDecimal(prefix), new MathContext(1000)); 

But I still get the same error. Should I apply it to the first line of that instead?

Comment: `prefix` should be initialized as a `BigDecimal`

Comment: I did tried this: currentPi = currentPi.multiply(prefix, new MathContext(1000)); and this: prefix = prefix.divide(new BigDecimal(fourthNumber), new MathContext(1000)); and them together but I still get the same error, even though it's a BigDecimal

Comment: So everything is a `BigDecimal`?

Comment: prefix, currentPi and pi are all prefixes.

Comment: I've moved this into its own question to prevent prolonged conversation here and because I've changed some code. Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781042/non-terminating-decimal-error-even-with-mathcontext

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this problem is at this line:

summationPi /= firstExponent.intValue()*secondExponent.intValue();

where the value of the secondExponent becomes so large as i increases that if you retrieve its int value using the intValue() method, you will get 0.